# Cygwin: "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: linux, cygwin, biometrics

I just downloaded a new app for 64 bit Linux (the app is BLAST+, but I don't think this has to do with the problem).

I'm trying to run it on a 64 bit Cygwin but get this error:

[image: cygwin screenshot]

Notice that I'm running it with a full path description, so I don't think the problem has anything to do with paths either..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785187/how-to-run-elf-binary-file-on-cygwin/40792991#40792991

Comment: @matzeri I'd submit that as an answer, pretty much all there is too it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the meanwhile I figured out what the problem was, and thought I'd leave an answer here in case it helps anyone in the future (unanswered questions get deleted eventually I think). The problem WAS indeed related to the program I was downloading - BLAST+. It turns out that if you want to run the Linux version of BLAST+ on a Cygwin emulator, you need to install additional software.

Instead of doing that, I found out that BLAST+ has a windows version. I downloaded that (.exe file) and now the BLAST functions run just fine from the windows command line.